# R-Stats: Add two arrays using factors

Tags: r, factors

Starting with two files as follows:

### test1.r

```
Crop, Value
Coconut, 12300
Amaranthus, 123
Cowpea, 100
Brinjal, 210
Coconut, 500
Brinjal, 10
Coconut, 1000
Cowpea, 105
```

### test2.r

```
Crop, Value
Rubber, 10
Cardamom, 22
Amaranthus,  12
Garcinia, 10
Brinjal, 10
Coconut, 1000
Brinjal, 25


> d1 = read.csv("test1.r")
> d2 = read.csv("test2.r")
> sum1 = tapply(d1$Value,d1$Crop,sum)
> sum2 = tapply(d2$Value,d2$Crop,sum)
> sum1
 Amaranthus    Brinjal    Coconut     Cowpea 
       123        220      13800        205 
> sum2
Amaranthus    Brinjal   Cardamom    Coconut   Garcinia     Rubber 
        12         35         22       1000         10         10
```

I would like to merge sum1 and sum2 into a single array by applying an operators such as 'sum' to the value, if the respective values if a factor exists in both the files (such as Amaranthus, Brinjal and Coconut), or just inserting the name-value pair if it only exists in one file. In short, the output should be as follows (transposed for convenience, and assuming the 'sum' operator):

```
Amaranthus  135
Brinjal  255
Cardamom 22
Coconut 14800
Cowpea 205
Garcinia 10
Rubber 10
```

TIA for any help,

s1b

Comment: `d <- rbind(d1, d2);  tapply(d$Value, d$Crop, sum)`?

Comment: Thanks! This does work. However, my actual requirement is to combine two non-conformable arrays (sum1 & sum2) into a single collapsed array.

Comment: `s3 <- c(s1,s2) ; s3 <- data.frame(Crop=names(s3),Value=s3) ; tapply(s3$Value,s3$Crop,sum)` should work. @Roland's appraoch is cleaner.